# What does std::filesystem::is_regular_file(path) mean on Windows?

Tags: c++, windows, c++17, std, std-filesystem

About `std::filesystem::is_regular_file(path)`, cppreference.com [says](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/is_regular_file):

> Checks if the given file status or path corresponds to a regular file […] Equivalent to `s.type() == file_type::regular`.

For example, in the Linux kernel, file types are declared in the header file `sys/stat.h`. The type name and symbolic name for each Linux file type is listed below:

- Socket (S_IFSOCK)
- Symbolic link (S_IFLNK)
- **Regular File** (S_IFREG)
- Block special file (S_IFBLK)
- Directory (S_IFDIR)
- Character device (S_IFCHR)
- FIFO (named pipe) (S_IFIFO)

What is the thing that this function checks on Windows?

Comment: It's exactly the same? There are regular files and other files like symlinks on Windows too. It looks like Microsoft's implementation might not do anything with symlinks https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/standard-library/filesystem-enumerations?view=msvc-170#file_type

Comment: @AlanBirtles I don't think Windows has symlinks for files, only directories (aka reparse points, aka junctions).  EDIT looking at the answer just posted here, seems I might be wrong.

Comment: @PaulSanders it does these days https://blogs.windows.com/windowsdeveloper/2016/12/02/symlinks-windows-10/#:~:text=Symlinks%2C%20or%20symbolic%20links%2C%20are,supported%20symlinks%20since%20Windows%20Vista. (Since vista)

Comment: @AlanBirtles Interesting, that's very welcome news.  And long overdue!

Comment: @PaulSanders to be fair, they've been available for 15 years so not particularly overdue

Comment: @AlanBirtles True.  Just rather low profile, not sure if many people know about them (I forgot about `mklink`, I use Sysinternals' Junction tool).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Since we are talking about Windows we can consider [MS implementation](https://github.com/microsoft/STL/blob/main/stl/inc/filesystem#L1980) of the standard library, and that's how they determine if the file is regular:

```
if (_Bitmask_includes(_Attrs, __std_fs_file_attr::_Reparse_point)) {
    if (_Stats._Reparse_point_tag == __std_fs_reparse_tag::_Symlink) {
        this->type(file_type::symlink);
        return;
    }

    if (_Stats._Reparse_point_tag == __std_fs_reparse_tag::_Mount_point) {
        this->type(file_type::junction);
        return;
    }

    // All other reparse points considered ordinary files or directories
}

if (_Bitmask_includes(_Attrs, __std_fs_file_attr::_Directory)) {
    this->type(file_type::directory);
} else {
    this->type(file_type::regular);
}
```

So if it isn't `IO_REPARSE_TAG_MOUNT_POINT`, `IO_REPARSE_TAG_SYMLINK` or a directory, then it is a regular file.

Comment: So when NFS clients store device nodes or fifos using IO_REPARSE_TAG_NFS, or when WSL stores device nodes using IO_REPARSE_TAG_LX_CHR, the stdlib considers them to be regular files?

Comment: @user1686 I've no idea about the attributes you mentioned, but you can see the code.

Comment: @ScottMcPeak added a link to the implementation. As to the citation: I've mentioned from the beginning that the code is from the MS implementation and there is only one standard C++ library from MS.